# Using PHP to fill Bootstrap Input - Error with spaces in string variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

This is a strange problem... wondering if anyone has run into this?
I have php embedded into a standard HTML page, and I'm using the php to insert data into various areas of a form on the page.  I'm using Bootstrap for the form elements.

I set a php variable such as this:

```
$myVar = "This is the text";
```

And down in the page, here is what the code looks like for the Bootstrap input:

```
<div class="input-field3"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="my-var" placeholder=<?php echo $myVar ?>></div>
```

When this page is viewed, only the word "This" is displayed in the Input.  The results are the same if I change from placeholder to value.  No matter how long I make the first word in the variable, it will display everything up to the first space.  I've also tried it with single or double quotes around the variable.

When I look at the page source, it appears correct, like this:

```
<div class="input-field3"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="my-var" placeholder=This is the text></div>
```

Any ideas or solutions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You don't have quotes around the value in the generated HTML.

Try this instead:

```
<div class="input-field3"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="my-var" placeholder="<?php echo $myVar ?>"></div>
```

Comment: Ugh... you're correct!  Thanks. Been looking at this too long and completely missed that.

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this

```
<div class="input-field3"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="my-var" placeholder="<?php echo $myVar ?>"></div>
```

Comment: <?= $myVar ?> is really bad practice, don't be lazy. Just use <?php echo $myVar ?>
This all has to do with php versions etc.